# Create MSI for Office Outlook Add-In with visual studio

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-installer, outlook-addin

I have create a c# application with a windows service and 2 vsto projects. Once the MSI has been created/installed i can see the one add-in was installed and the service is deployed as well. My problem comes in where only one of the vsto projects is installed. The one that is giving me nightmares is a Outlook visual designer ribbon. The other vsto project is a non visual add-in, and that one installs just fine. For the life of me i can't figure out why the visual designer is not installing, it is not in outlook options and not in control panel/add remove either. Compiling it from Visual studio everything works fine and runs as it should. Does anyone maybe have an idea of what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have one MSI from either project, and one installing fine and the other does nothing; or do you expect a single MSI created from the solution to contain the add-ins from both projects?

Comment: Ye i created one MSI with all three projects included, was this dumb of me to expect it to work? If i exclude the one visual designer project and only build the msi with service and one vsto then it works fine. Other way round also breaks the msi when its just the service and visual designer project. So it has to be something with the visual designer project. I do wish to know it should be possible to add 2 add-ins to one msi right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see your add-in listed on the COM add-ins dialog the required windows registry keys were not added properly. See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Make sure that you did all the necessary steps described in the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article.